# How to avoid Jenkins multibranch pipeline job triggering itself

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I would like my Jenkins multibranch pipeline job to avoid triggering itself.  The job makes a commit because it increments the version file and checks it into source control which causes an endless loop.

In a regular job I can follow [these instructions](https://liviutudor.com/2015/12/09/jenkins-ci-trick-to-prevent-task-from-triggering-itself-on-scm-commit/#sthash.MbNk0w7n.dpbs) to avoid this loop (although it's not the cleanest way).

The instructions do not work for a multibranch pipeline (there is no 'ignore commits from certain users' option).  Is there any way in a Jenkins mulitbranch pipeline to prevent a self-triggered commit?

Comment: Not really a definitive solution yet but in case it helps others I found two ways I could make this work.  First, I can disable automatic builds on a set of branches by changing the `Property strategy` to `Named branches get different properties` and then choosing `Suppress automatic SCM triggering` under `Add property`.  Second, I was able to configure Bitbucket to suppress push notifications for certain users.  By doing this I could suppress builds for the build server user which is the same approach used by the article I linked.  However, I don't know if other repos support this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline Scan infinite re-build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49736540/jenkins-multibranch-pipeline-scan-infinite-re-build)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A workaround if using GIT:

When bumping the version and committing, use a specific message in the commit log eg: *[git-version-bump] - Bumping the version*

After scm checkout, check if the last commit was a version bump commit, if it is, abort the job.

```
stage('Checkout') {
    checkout scm
    if (lastCommitIsBumpCommit()) {
        currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'
        error('Last commit bumped the version, aborting the build to prevent a loop.')
    } else {
        echo('Last commit is not a bump commit, job continues as normal.')
    }
}

private boolean lastCommitIsBumpCommit() {
    lastCommit = sh([script: 'git log -1', returnStdout: true])
    if (lastCommit.contains("[git-version-bump]")) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I've done but it introduces an issue with my git server integration (bitbucket). The build for the version bump still "runs" so the "build status" badge displayed in bitbucket references the "latest" build which is a no-op instead of the build that actually did something. Really need a way to prevent the pipeline from running at all.

Comment: I do the same, but use `result = 'NOT_BUILT'` as I believe it's semantically more appropriate. See also: https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Result.html