# Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline Scan infinite re-build

Tags: git, maven, jenkins-pipeline

I have to deal with the following scenario:

1. I am running my Jenkins Pipeline on Blue Ocean + Git (+ Maven).
2. I have setup the "Scan Multibranch Pipeline" option to check every **X** minutes if something has changed on the Git repo, and in that case  start the job again...
3. My pipeline implements the usual build and test stages.
4. My pipeline, as last stage, increments the snapshot version and pushes the updated POM to Git.

**Step 4 triggers my issue**: the "Scan Multibranch Pipeline" feature gets (forever) the branch as updated (by the commit at step 4).

How could I update the last "Scan Multibranch Pipeline" commit hash reference in order to stop job re-triggering?

Thank you in advance!
Antonio

Comment: A simple way would be to check the Git commit message before running  your other pipeline steps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Colleague of mine wrote a plugin,

https://github.com/jenkinsci/ignore-committer-strategy-plugin
Adds a 'Ignore committer' strategy.

We used this to blacklist our CI Machine user. If the changeset contained the machine user, it would not be built.

Answer (score 0):

As @mkobit pointed out you can use a commit message and check that message again if you have already done that job and if there is no message commit it
Here is the detailed link
[How to avoid Jenkins multibranch pipeline job triggering itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45696788/how-to-avoid-jenkins-multibranch-pipeline-job-triggering-itself?rq=1)